# Dual Monitors Mac OS X - CMD + TAB AND move mouse to focused Application

Tags: mac, keyboard, multiple-monitors, osx-lion, mouse

On my computer setup I have dual monitors, one is vertical for code and the other is horizontal for the web browser. I am new to Mac OS X and was wondering if it was possible when switching apps with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to move the mouse to that application screen. For example, I may have my mouse in the far left hand corner of my vertical monitor and I hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. This switches to my web browser, but my mouse stays on the vertical monitor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Closest I have found is to use CatchMouse http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/CatchMouse.shtml

Shortcuts to move mouse to different monitor.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AltTab](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/) to have an alternative shortcut for *command+tab*, which moves the mouse cursor along with moving focus on the app/screen.